# Route53 Subdomain delegation and Elasticbeanstalk Question

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Here is my scenario:

1. I have purchased a domain thru Route53 say -- example.com ( Account A)
2. I have created an elasticbeanstalk application say rusty.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com ( Account B)
3. I now want my URL to become rusty.example.com instead of rusty.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com ( account B)
4. This is what I have done -- 
   a. created a hosted zone in Account B : rusty.example.com and copied the NS records.
   b. created a hosted zone rusty.example.com in Account A and copied the NS records from account B.
5. In Account B, created an alias record rusty.example.com with a value equal to rusty.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com.

Where do you think I am making a mistake ?

Appreciate any HELP.

Thanks !

Comment: I'd just have account A control example.com  (root not rusty) and add a CNAME there mapping rusty.example.com to your beanstalk.  You don't need DNS records in B, you don't need namservers for the subdomain.   You only need something more complicated if you need to change what rusty.example.com points to later only by ONLY making changes in account B, without updating account A.

Comment: Thanks @Dave S. Just claryfying the steps before I make the changes - 1, create a Cname record in account A rusty,example.com == rusty.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com and no DNS changes in account B ? correct ?

Comment: @ Dave S I tried your suggestion. Did not work. No Route 53 records in Account B and added an entry in Account A. Created a CNAME record for rusty.example.com to match to rusty.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com (Account A). Please HELP.

Comment: does http:// rusty.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com work in your browser?  What does `ping rusty.example.com` display?